# Writing to temp directory when app launched via "Open with"

Tags: windows, visual-c++, system32

My application (written in Visual C++ 2008) saves a file with extension .xxx (for example). If I right-click on a file with that extension, select "Open with", and then select my application, any programmatic writing to a file inside my application to a temp directory or even to the directory of the file I opened gets redirected automatically (I assume by Windows) to C:\windows\system32. This behavior does not occur when the file is opened inside the application using File > Open or by double-clicking on the file. This redirection to system32 probably started when I switched from Visual C++ 6.0 or with Windows 7, I don't know which. The program has been successfully running for 13 years. I tried to capture in code the current working directory after opening the file via "Open with" by extracting the directory path of the file but it is annoyingly changed to C:\windows\system32. Even the path obtained from GetTempPath is changed to C:\windows\system32. I am assuming Windows security is causing this to happen. Does anyone know anything about this.

Answer (score 0):

Please read carefully the documentation of the [GetTempPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364992) function

1. The path specified by the TMP environment variable.
2. The path specified by the TEMP environment variable.
3. The path specified by the USERPROFILE environment variable.
4. The Windows directory

So there is a change, that the windows directory gets selected as temp path...

Also, please verify that your application has a valid Vista manifest! If this is not existend, then several redirections and virtualisation will happen with your application:

```
<?xmlversion="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Or are you talking about the current working directory? The current working directory is mostly "%`SYSTEMROOT%\system32` for shell-starting...

Comment: The manifest is created by Visual Studio 2008 and is embedded in the exe. 

The problem far exceeds GetTempPath and why would it work correctly for 13 years in all modes (File > Open, double-click on exe, and Open with) and now fail for Open with?

Also and most bizarre, AfxMessageBox doesn't work when the application is opened with Open with. I can't get AfxMessageBox to display a message from many parts of the program.

Comment: Setting the working directory solved the problems. I guess it wasn't necessary when the code was compiled with Visual C++ 6.0.